# Why does postgresql differentiate between named and numeric time zone notations?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-10, timezone

Why is there a difference between named timezone and numeric timezone offset, both of which yield different UTC timestamps for `TIMESTAMPTZ`?

Assume `Europe/Prague` timezone, which is currently `+02:00` (DST); time of writing is `2018-08-25`.

As you can check e.g. [via google](https://www.google.cz/search?q=prague+timezone):

[image: uploaded image]

Also, in my postgres installation I can query it:

```
SELECT utc_offset FROM pg_timezone_names where name = 'Europe/Prague';
```

Which also yields `02:00:00`.

Then, why on earth, do I get two different UTC timestamps when running following two queries?

The following yields `2018-08-25T20:00:00.000Z` (`2018-08-25 18:00:00-02`):

```
SET TIME ZONE '+02:00'; -- with or without the plus
SELECT '2018-08-25 18:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ;
```

The following yields `2018-08-25T16:00:00.000Z` (`2018-08-25 18:00:00+02`), which is correct:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Prague';
SELECT '2018-08-25 18:00:00'::TIMESTAMPTZ;
```

Why does postgres differentiate those two notations?

Comment: DST (daylight saving time) changes according to countries. For example, 2 different countries with same offset but one uses DST and the other does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, [as documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES), one uses POSIX and other uses ISO-8601.

> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names,
>   positive offsets are used for locations west of Greenwich. Everywhere
>   else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive
>   timezone offsets are east of Greenwich.

Comment: But docs say that POSIX is in format `STDoffset`, so `+02:00` shouldn't be POSIX, which is corroborated by docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONE-TABLE), which say that it's ISO-8601. Then why does it result in `-02` UTC offset, which is incorrect (my first example in OP)?

Comment: Accepting since you're right, but I made a [follow-up question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215905/why-does-postgresql-interpret-numeric-utc-offset-as-posix-and-not-iso-8601), to figure out why this is so.