# Why does PostgreSQL interpret numeric UTC offset as POSIX and not ISO-8601?

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-10, timezone

Setting time zone as numeric offset (without `abbrev`, thus IMO not in POSIX format) is still interpreted by PostgreSQL as POSIX format:

```
SET TIME ZONE '+02:00';
```

At least I assume, because checking the UTF offset via:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM now()) * interval '1sec';
```

yields `-02:00:00`, which means the offset from Greenwich is reversed as noted in docs:

> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names, positive offsets are used for locations west of Greenwich. Everywhere else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive timezone offsets are east of Greenwich.

Setting via named time zone yields positive offset from UTC, which is correct:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Prague'; -- +02:00 DST at time of writing
SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM now()) * interval '1sec'; -- `02:00:00`
```

[Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) state there are 3 ways to specify time zone, none of which mention the `+00:00` numeric syntax:

> PostgreSQL allows you to specify time zones in three different forms:
>
> - A full time zone name, for example `America/New_York`. The recognized time zone names are listed in the `pg_timezone_names` view (see [Section 51.90](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-timezone-names.html)). PostgreSQL uses the widely-used IANA time zone data for this purpose, so the same time zone names are also recognized by much other software.
> - A time zone abbreviation, for example `PST`. Such a specification merely defines a particular offset from UTC, in contrast to full time zone names which can imply a set of daylight savings transition-date rules as well. The recognized abbreviations are listed in the `pg_timezone_abbrevs` view (see [Section 51.89](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-timezone-abbrevs.html)). You cannot set the configuration parameters [TimeZone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) or [log_timezone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-TIMEZONE) to a time zone abbreviation, but you can use abbreviations in date/time input values and with the `AT TIME ZONE` operator.
> - In addition to the timezone names and abbreviations, PostgreSQL will accept POSIX-style time zone specifications of the form *`STDoffset`* or *`STD`**`offset`**`DST`* [...]

But since the POSIX (point 3 above) doesn't mention the `±00:00` format anywhere (only that it requires `STD` abbrev), I assume it does not fall into that category.

Furthermore, [elsewhere in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONE-TABLE) the `±00:00` is explicitly specified as `ISO 8601`. Though I understand that applies to `TIMESTAMPTZ` datatype, and not runtime `timezone` configuration, it seems weird for postgres to interpret the same format in two different ways.

On top of that, the `±00:00` format is mentioned on wikipedia as [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC).

**Q1:** So, does Postgres really interpret the `±00:00` as POSIX (or is there something else going on), and why?

**Q2:** Also, is there a definitive list of which formats that you can set either in `postgresql.conf` or at runtime via `SET TIME ZONE` are interpreted as POSIX, and which as ISO-8601?

---

(This question is a continuation of my previous: [Why does postgresql differentiate between named and numeric time zone notations?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215877/why-does-postgresql-differentiate-between-named-and-numeric-time-zone-notations)  Thanks [jjanes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34857/jjanes) for pointing me in the right direction.)

---

**EDIT (18-08-26 18:56) to reflect [Erwin's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/215911/78639):**

First, the `SET` docs state (added list numbers, emphasis):

> `SET TIME ZONE value` is an alias for `SET timezone TO value`. The syntax `SET TIME ZONE` allows special syntax for the time zone specification. Here are examples of valid values:
>
> 1. `'PST8PDT'`
>
>    The time zone for Berkeley, California.
> 2. `'Europe/Rome'`
>
>    The time zone for Italy.
> 3. `-7`
>
>    The time zone 7 hours west from UTC (equivalent to PDT). Positive values are east from UTC.
> 4. `INTERVAL '-08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE`
>
>    The time zone 8 hours west from UTC (equivalent to PST).
>
> [...]
>
> **Timezone settings given as numbers or intervals are internally translated to POSIX timezone syntax.** For example, after `SET TIME ZONE -7`, `SHOW TIME ZONE` would report `<-07>+07`.

The emphasized sentence is either wrong, incomplete, or else I don't understand it at all.

1. does it mean that their POSIX-ish string (1), it being a string, is interpreted as ISO-8601? Let's test that.

   ```
   SET TIME ZONE 'PST8PDT';
   SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM now()) * interval '1sec';
   ```

   Yields `-07:00:00`, which is negative, and negative values are west of Greenwich only in ISO-8601, since the [docs state](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) (emphasis mine):

   > Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names, positive offsets are used for locations *west* of Greenwich. **Everywhere else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive timezone offsets are *east* of Greenwich.**

   Unless that quote above still only applies timestamp literals.

   If not, it seems that `'PST8PDT'` string is indeed interpreted as ISO-8601.

   But,

   ```
   SET TIME ZONE 'UTC2';
   SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM now()) * interval '1sec';
   ```

   yields `-02:00:00`.. So are we back in POSIX again? Or is `UTC2` not a POSIX *`STDoffset`* format?
2. The number format `-7` is specified to be interpreted as POSIX, so let's test that again:

   ```
   SET TIME ZONE 2;
   SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM now()) * interval '1sec';
   ```

   yields `02:00:00`. Hmm.. that sounds ISO-8601 enough to me. +2 hours, east of Greenwich.
3. Where does `'+02:00'` fall into? It's not a number, not an interval, though it acts as if postgres parses it as interval, because it results in POSIX offsets:

   ```
   SET TIME ZONE '+02:00';
   SELECT EXTRACT(TIMEZONE FROM now()) * interval '1sec';
   ```

   Yields `-02:00:00`.

So I'm still confused. One other questions that comes to mind:

**Q3**: does west/east of Greenwich plus/minus reversal for POSIX apply just for timestamp literals, or time zone configuration, too?

Answer (score 3):

The manual can easily be misread there. Quoting the [same source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES), but with one more leading sentence:

> All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They
> are converted to local time in the zone specified by the [TimeZone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE)
> configuration parameter before being displayed to the client.
>
> PostgreSQL allows you to specify time zones in three different forms:
>
> [...]

This paragraph deals with what's allowed in the ***TimeZone configuration parameter*** (and, accordingly, the `AT TIME ZONE` construct).

The part of the [manual you quote](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONE-TABLE) further down in your question deals with ***Time Zone Input*** in **timestamp literals** which follows the mentioned ISO-8601 convention.

You need [**this** part of the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) explaining what's allowed for `SET TIME ZONE` (and the `AT TIME ZONE` construct):

> `TIME ZONE`
>
> `SET TIME ZONE` value is an alias for `SET timezone TO`*`value`*.
> The syntax `SET TIME ZONE` allows special syntax for the time zone
> specification. Here are examples of valid values:
>
> `'PST8PDT'`
> The time zone for Berkeley, California.
>
> `'Europe/Rome'`
> The time zone for Italy.
>
> `-7`
> The time zone 7 hours west from UTC (equivalent to PDT). Positive values are east from UTC.
>
> `INTERVAL '-08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE`
> The time zone 8 hours west from UTC (equivalent to PST).
>
> [...]

In your example `SET TIME ZONE '+02:00';` *looks* like an interval, but that's deceiving. Only explicitly declaring `INTERVAL` makes Postgres treat it as *interval*. `'+02:00'` is just another case of *`STDoffset`*, with no leading `STD`, hence defaulting to UTC. So:

```
SET TIME ZONE '+02:00';
```

... is equivalent to:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'UTC+02:00';
```

These quotes [from the first manual page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES) seem instrumental:

> The default time zone is specified as a constant numeric offset from UTC.

And:

> One should be wary that the POSIX-style time zone feature can lead to
> silently accepting bogus input, since there is no check on the
> reasonableness of the zone abbreviations. For example, `SET TIMEZONE TO FOOBAR0`
> will work, leaving the system effectively using a rather
> peculiar abbreviation for UTC. Another issue to keep in mind is that
> in POSIX time zone names, positive offsets are used for locations west
> of Greenwich. Everywhere else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601
> convention that positive timezone offsets are east of Greenwich.

But the manual does not seem to mention that the *`STD`* part can be *missing* from the specification. Seems like a documentation bug ...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm somewhat still confused (if not more). Edited the question with more elaboration below the fold.

Comment: @Dwelle: Right, I haddn't addressed your case of `'+02:00'`. I added some more.

Comment: so `'+02:00'` is treated as POSIX, but why is `'PST8PDT'` treated as ISO (yielding negative, west-of-Greenwich offset `-07:00:00`), and most importantly, why is `-7` treated as ISO, too, despite docs saying numbers are treated as POSIX (see my addendum from yesterday)? Or does the _"Timezone settings given as numbers or intervals are internally translated to POSIX timezone syntax"_ only refer to output of `SHOW TIME ZONE`, and not how they are parsed/interpreted in the first place?